# Numeric literals in Java - octal?

Tags: java, literals, octal

Here is some code in java on datatypes:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i = -0777;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is -511

If the code is changed to :

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i = -777;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The output is -777.

Why is the output differing??? What are the calculations done behind this code???

Comment: I would upvote this question, but the title is way too general and unspecific.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with data types. It is about numeric literals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-0777` is treated by the compiler as an octal number (base 8) whose decimal value is -511 (-(64*7+8*7+7)). `-777` is a decimal number.

Comment: what happens if I input “-077” via STDIN?

Comment: @RishavKundu "-077" is a String. There are numerous ways you can interpret/parse it.

Comment: @RishavKundu That would depend on how you read it from STDIN. For example - `Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println (sc.nextInt ());` will print -77 if you type in -077.